# how to link windows form application setup file with an access database file

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I started a project using ms access as my database with a local *.accdb file, but then soon realized that when I create an installer, and install on another system. I get an error saying database not found, because that server doesn't have that access file at that location as i mentioned in my code.  So my question is: What is the norm? How i can link and retrieve database in windows forms applications after creating setup..?

Comment: You have a connection string stored in your config file. You change that connection string to adapt to the different environment. This is the job for your setup program.